# what logic does git follow to determine that remote contains work not available in local repository

Tags: git

Often times when I push commits to remote they get rejected because remote contains work that I don't have locally. I'm wondering what precise logic does git follow to arrive at that conclusion? I've tried googling but haven't found a good account of the process. I may assume that in order for the commit to be pushed to the remote branch this commit being pushed has to have all commits available on remote branch as it's ancestors, is it correct? For example, the following exists:

```
A-B-C (remote master branch)
 \
  A-D (local master branch)
```

When I do git push origin master git takes all commits available on origin/master (possibly from the point of common ancestor - `A` here) and checks whether the last commit I try to push (now it's commit `D`) has them as its ancestors. Something like this in pseudocode:

```
foreach (commitsInOriginMaster as commit) {
    if (!localCommitToPush.hasAncestor(commit)) {
        rejectPush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR executive summary

The push is allowed or denied by the *remote*, based on whether the result is a "fast-forward".  A fast-forward occurs (as you've already guessed) when the new target of a label has the old target of that label as an ancestor.

#### Long discussion version

There are two things I think you need to understand here.  The first is that git does this based on "references", and a non-forced push is allowed if it's a "fast-forward", so you need to get (in some deep grasp-y sense) what a "fast-forward" is.

The second, and perhaps actually more important in this case, is that it's the *remote* that decides whether your operation is a "fast forward".  This bit is pretty crucial because git is distributed, and your push may be happening at the same time<sup>1</sup> as someone else's push.

#### Examples of what is and is not a fast-forward

Let's handle the first of these first because it's a bit easier.  As you've already noted, "has ancestor" is the key test.  Let me draw a few commit chains like you did, but I'll label each node uniquely and add a few more offshoots and re-merges.  And, I'll add some labels pointing to each "tip-most" commit:

```
    B
  /   \
A - C - D - E    <-- L1
  \
    F - G        <-- L2
```

Now, suppose there's another label (such as `master` for instance) pointing to one of these commits `A` through `G`.  We can ask git to move *any* label from *any* commit to any other, with `git update-ref` (a low level command that simply obeys us without question, rather than checking whether it's a wise thing to do):

```
git update-ref <refname> <commit-id>
```

Or we can be much safer and use smarter, higher-level commands that check whether some operation is a "fast forward".  So what is a fast forward?

Well, imagine our label-in-question points to commit `A`.  If we tell git to move it to any other commit, git simply tests one thing: "is `A` an ancestor of the new commit?"  If so, that's a "fast forward".  If not, it's not.  And since `A` is the (only) root commit, it's always an ancestor of every other commit, so this is always a fast-forward.

Imagine instead that our label points to `B`.  If we ask git to move it to `A`, that's *not* a fast-forward.  If we ask git to move it to `F` or `G`, those also are not fast-forward operations.  Even `C` is not fast-forward, because `C`'s only ancestor is `A`.  But `D` and `E` both have `B` as an ancestor, so moving our label from `B` to `E` is a fast-forward.

Another (maybe simpler) way to look at this is: *from any commit, all of the commits in that commit's history are find-able* ("reachable"), because each commit points back to its parent(s).  (In `D`'s case, it points to both `B` and `C`: it's a merge commit and has two parents.)  Given this fact, a fast-forward label move is a move that, if made, leaves every commit *previously* reachable from that label, *still* reachable from that label.  A non-fast-forward would make some commit(s) that are currently findable, no longer reachable—at least, not from that label.  (Some other label, like `L1` or `L2`, may keep it reachable in a more global sense, but that doesn't count when defining fast-forward-ness.)

#### Pushes are allowed or denied by the remote

Now let's look at the second part of this.  When you run `git push remote refspec`,<sup>2</sup> your git contacts a remote git (or git emulator) and has a little conversation with it: "what labels do you have, and what SHA-1s do they point to?"  Your git then figures out which commits and other objects that (1) you have, (2) they don't, and (3) they will need if your push is to succeed.  Your git packages these up<sup>3</sup> and sends them over.  It's only *after* all this that the remote decides whether to allow the push.

Once everything is in place on the remote, the remote looks at what your git gave it, and what labels your git has told it to set.  It looks at where those label point *right now*, on the remote.  If the label does not exist (e.g., you're creating a new branch or tag), that's fine (so far at least).<sup>4</sup>  If the label *does* exist, the label may have to move.

For a branch label, the remote will check whether that move is, *on the remote*, a fast-forward.  If so, the move is allowed (again, so far at least).  If not, the move is denied as a "non-fast-forward" unless you set the force flag.<sup>5</sup>

(For tag moves, older gits use the branch rules, and newer ones just say no unless forced.)

Eventually, after the remote has taken a look at all your proposed label-changes, it either allows some or all of them, or denies some or all of them.  Then, once it's done, the remote has a new set of labels pointing to either new-and-updated, or the same old, commits.

At that point, if there's someone else also waiting in line to push, the remote allows their push to begin by exchanging information, packaging up objects, and proposing label-moves.  (In fact, that's normally handled by a separate process on the server, at least assuming a standard git build.  If two are started "simultaneously", they have a race to take a lock: one wins and goes first, and the other waits until the lock is released.  If more than two are started, again there's a winner, after which the remaining pushers go for the lock again, and so on.)

The reason for this rule, which is simple but effective, is that by definition a fast-forward can never *lose* a commit.  It always simply adds some (perhaps zero) *new* commits to the graph.  Everything that was reachable is still reachable, and maybe there is more too.

If you want to know in advance whether a push will be permitted, you can connect to the remote and ask it for where its labels are now.  That's precisely what `git fetch` does:  It asks the remote what the remote has, and records all that in your repository.  Now you can run the test on what you have in your repository—but the flaw in this method is that whatever answer you get, it may be out of date by the time you're able to run `git push`.  It generally takes a very busy repository for this to become a problem, though.

---

<sup>1</sup>Albert Einstein notwithstanding :-) ... in this case "same time" is really "as decided by the remote", which locks against other remote updates while it does yours, and vice versa.

<sup>2</sup>In this case, your refspec is `master:master`, even if you just spell it `master`.  The most important part on *your* side is the commit you identify on the left; but the most important part on the *remote* is the label-name you supply on the right, because that's the one you're asking the remote to change.

<sup>3</sup>With a "smart" protocol, this is literally true: your git builds a "thin pack" and then sends that over.  That's what the "counting objects" and "compressing" is about: building the pack, then throwing lots of CPU time at it to make it as small as feasible before sending it over the wire.

<sup>4</sup>Remotes can have "git hooks" that can impose additional requirements, such as "only someone coming in as user `release` may move `master`" or "anyone can create a branch as long as its name starts with `refs/heads/user`, otherwise only blessed people may create them".  These days most of the fancy control seems to be done with gitolite.

<sup>5</sup>You can set this flag globally with `--force`, or per-refspec with a leading plus sign.

Comment: thanks a lot for such an elaborate answer! Let me go through it and try to wrap my head around it and I'll soon get back with questions :)

Comment: @torek, I've a clarifying question. I assume that fast-forward on remote is performed using `--ff-only` flag and denied if it's not ff. What happens if I specify `--force` option when pushing? Does git move branch pointer as if it was a fast-forward merge regardless of commits being lost? Where can I read a simplified version of what happens internally with forced push? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, it's more that (merge's) `--ff-only` is performed using the underlying "is fast forward" check: there's just a bit of code built in that does the "is this a fast forward" test.  Anyway, yes, with `--force` the receiver side of the push will just move the branch pointer as requested.  That's really all force means: "skip the is-fast-forward check".  (Newer gits have a "force with lease" option which hands the remote a bit more info: "I expect your ref name X to resolve to SHA-1 Y, if so replace it with Z, if not tell me about an error.")